# Regex with non repeating letter in word

Tags: java, regex

I am stumped on a problem.

This problem requires involves a clue which has missing letters. There is an array of words that are to be matched against the clue, however, the word should only match if it does not already have a letter from the clue.

I am using a regex and it is matching all instances of the match but I can't figure out how to exclude the ones that have a repeating letter in the word
list.

e.g., clue is `aba???` therefore, `abaton` should match, but `abatua` should not as there is an `a` in both words and the clue part that is masked by the `???`

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MatchTest {

    public ArrayList<String> wordLookup(ArrayList<String> wordList, String clue) {
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        String regex = clue.replaceAll("\\?", "\\.?");

        for (int i = 0; i < wordList.size(); i++) {
            if (wordList.get(i).matches(regex)) {
                arrayList.add(wordList.get(i));
            }
        }
        return arrayList;
    }
}

    class MatchTestMain {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            MatchTest mt = new MatchTest();
            ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();

            wordList.add("abandon");
            wordList.add("wanton");
            wordList.add("abaton");
            wordList.add("abator");
            wordList.add("abatua");

            System.out.println(mt.wordLookup(wordList, "aba???"));
        }
}
```

I am getting this output

```
[abaton, abator, abatua]
```

But the correct output would be

```
[abaton, abator]
```

Any ideas?

Edit for completeness: I found an edge case where the clue is all ?, e.g., clue is ??????, it would cause an Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character [^]

I extended the solution proposed by @Malte Hartwig to account for the edge case.

Here is the final version:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MatchTest {

    public ArrayList<String> wordLookup(ArrayList<String> wordList, String clue) {
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        String givenLetters = clue.replaceAll("\\?", "");
        String regex = clue.replaceAll("\\?", "\\[^" + givenLetters + "]");
        String regex2 = clue.replaceAll("\\?", "\\.?");

        if (givenLetters.length() == 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < wordList.size(); i++) {
                if (wordList.get(i).matches(regex2) && wordList.get(i).length() == clue.length()) {
                    arrayList.add(wordList.get(i));
                }
            }
        }

        if (givenLetters.length() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < wordList.size(); i++) {
                if (wordList.get(i).matches(regex)) {
                    arrayList.add(wordList.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
        return arrayList;
    }
}

    class MatchTestMain {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            MatchTest mt = new MatchTest();
            ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<>();

            wordList.add("abandon");
            wordList.add("wanton");
            wordList.add("abaton");
            wordList.add("abator");
            wordList.add("abatua");

            System.out.println(mt.wordLookup(wordList, "ab??o?"));
            System.out.println(mt.wordLookup(wordList, "?b????"));
            System.out.println(mt.wordLookup(wordList, "abatua"));
            System.out.println(mt.wordLookup(wordList, "a?a???"));
            System.out.println(mt.wordLookup(wordList, "?ridge"));
            System.out.println(mt.wordLookup(wordList, "aba???"));
            System.out.println(mt.wordLookup(wordList, "??????"));
        }
}
```

output:

```
[]
[abaton, abator, abatua]
[abatua]
[abaton, abator]
[]
[abaton, abator]
[wanton, abaton, abator, abatua]
```

Comment: `String regex = clue.replaceAll("\\?", "\\.?");` just replaces the `?` with `.?`. Why is that necessary? In this scenario, `abc???` would have a regex `abc.?.?.?`, which is wrong.

Comment: Also, will the word and clue always be 6 letters long with 3 masked letters, or can it be random?

Comment: @Coffeehouse Coder, the ".?" is required for the regex to work, "." also seems to work. No, it is random, only used for example as it is hard to find valid examples.

Comment: replace your clue + ['?']*n with clue + '[' + clue + ']{n}' to generate a faster matching regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first extract a list of letters that are given in the clue:

```
String givenLetters = clue.replaceAll("\\?", "");
// givenLetters = "aba"
```

If you use that list in your regex, you can tell the masked char **not** to be one of those given letters:

```
String regex = clue.replaceAll("\\?", "\\[^" + givenLetters + "]");
// regex = "aba[^aba][^aba][^aba]";
```

This replaces your `.?` by `[^aba]` in your example, meaning "anything not `a` or `b`" (or `a`, which is irrelevant in this case).

It should also work for clues that do not just have `?` at the end, like `??a?b?`, which would result in `pattern = [^ab][^ab]a[^ab]b[^ab]`.

Comment: Thanks, this works for my simple test case. I was trying something similar with having just the giveLetters but it was getting too complex trying to loop through and check against the nonGivenLetters and trying to do if conditions for indexOf.

Answer (score -1):

did some changes in your program..it is giving required output

package testProgram;

```
            import java.util.ArrayList;

            class MatchTest {
            public ArrayList<String> wordLookup(ArrayList<String> wordList, String clue) {
                ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

                // String regex = clue.replaceAll("\\?", "\\.?");

                for (int i = 0; i < wordList.size(); i++) {
                    if (wordList.get(i).matches(clue)) {
                        arrayList.add(wordList.get(i));
                    }
                }
                return arrayList;
            }

        }

        public class MatchTestMain {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                MatchTest mt = new MatchTest();
                ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();

                wordList.add("abandon");
                wordList.add("wanton");
                wordList.add("abaton");
                wordList.add("abator");
                wordList.add("abatua");

                System.out.println(mt.wordLookup(wordList, "(aba)[^aba]{0,3}"));
            }
        }
```

(aba)[^aba]{0,3} means first 3 chars will remain constant (aba) rest 0-3 chars will not contains any character from these 3 i.e. (aba).

{0,3} means at least 0 and at most 3 char.

Comment: Thanks but I don't know the clue or words that are being give, I only gave an example. The solution is too specific. It doesn't compile, you need to remove the public from public class.

Comment: well I tried to make it more dynamic...public ArrayList<String> wordLookup(ArrayList<String> wordList, String clue) {
  ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
  String matchingStr = clue.substring(0, 3);
  String regex = clue.replaceAll("\\?", "\\[^" + matchingStr + "]?");
  System.out.println(regex);
  for (int i = 0; i < wordList.size(); i++) {
   if (wordList.get(i).matches(regex)) {
    arrayList.add(wordList.get(i));
   }
  }
  return arrayList;